# Using \matbb{Z} and \textregistered in Math Mode

Tags: fonts, math-mode, errors

How can you use the two symbols in the Math mode?

My tex

```
$\matbb{Z}$
$\textregistered$
```

My formatting code

\documentclass{bmcart}

```
%%% Load packages
%\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
%\RequirePackage{natbib}
%\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
%\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} %applemac support if unicode package fails
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %UNIX support if unicode package fails
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage[T4, OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newunicodechar{ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\selectfont\m f}}
\newunicodechar{Ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\selectfont\m F}}
```

I get these warnings and errors

> LaTeX Warning: Command \textregistered invalid in math mode on input
>   line 248.
>
> LaTeX Warning: Command \textcircled invalid in math mode on input line
>   248.
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd)
>
> LaTeX Warning: Command \textcircled invalid in math mode on input line
>   248.
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/it' in size <8> not
>   available (Font)
>
> l.373  $\matbb
>                 {Z}$ [3] Overfull \hbox (4.19527pt too wide) detected at line 404  $\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ^^K < ^^L \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 :
>   \OML/cmm/m/it/10 Q\OT1/cmr/m/n/1 0 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ^^Ue[]
>   \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 + \OML/cmm/m/it/10 ^^Ve[]\OT1/cmr/m/ n/10
>   )(\OML/cmm/m/it/10 x; ^^Q\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ) = \OMS/cmsy/m/n/10
>   j\OML/cmm/m/ it/10 ^^U\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 j[]\OML/cmm/m/it/10
>   ^^N[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/ it/10 ^^V\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ) +
>   \OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 j\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ^^V\OMS/cmsy/m/ n/10
>   j[]\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ^^N[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10
>   ^^V\OT1/cmr/m/n /10 ) + 2\OML/cmm/m/it/10 Re\OT1/cmr/m/n/10
>   (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ^^U[]e[]\OT1/cmr/ m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10
>   x\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ))1[](\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ^^Q\OT1/cmr/m/ n/10
>   )\OML/cmm/m/it/10 =\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ^^L
>   \OMS/cmsy/m/n/10  ^^@ \OML/cmm/m/it/10 ^^K\OT1/cmr/m/n/10
>   )\OML/cmm/m/it/10 :$
>
> LaTeX Warning: Command \m invalid in math mode on input line 413.

and in a separate window:

[image]

Comment: Isn't it a typo? `matbb` instead of `mathbb`?

Comment: `matbb` instead of `mathbb`? And try `$\text{\textregistered}$`.

Comment: `Ƒ`, `ƒ` and `\text<anything>` are text-mode characters/macros. To include them in math-mode, use `\text`, e.g. `\text{\textcircled}`.

Comment: Also, be aware that the basic LaTeX `\textregistered` command produces a "faked" symbol. To get a better-looking symbol, be sure to load the `textcomp` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `mathbb` instead of `matbb` and try `$\text{\textregistered}$` instead of `$\textregistered$`.

Also, be aware that the basic `LaTeX` `\textregistered` command produces a "faked" symbol. To get a better-looking symbol, be sure to load the `textcomp` package.